# Unresolved function or method query() when using 'node-redshift' module

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, javascript-objects

```
var Redshift = require('node-redshift');

var client = {
    user: 'user',
    database: 'database',
    password: 'password',
    port: 'port',
    host: 'host',
};

var redshiftClient = new Redshift(client, { rawConnection: true });

redshiftClient.query();
```

**Redshift** has a query function, but when it is used as new Redshift assigned to redshiftClient it is being unresolved.

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any errors being logged out? Posting those alongside your problem can help pinpoint where something is going wrong.

Comment: There is no error. The command does not get executed because it says "Unresolved function or method query". That is about it.

Comment: Hm ok, and are you providing any parameters to that query() method when you're calling it in your code?